# Omen Machine and no library

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So [Omen Machine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233042) is on the field and an opponent just used [Jace, the Mind Sculptor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=413599)'s ultimate to exile my library and I have no cards in hand, so no library left.  When it is my turn, do I lose?  Opponent think so, but since I am not drawing due to Omen Machine, I believe I survive and the exile command fizzles.  We couldn't find any specific rules to address the situation so called a draw (I still think I'm right though).

Anyone able to clarify this ruling?

Comment: Wow Omen Machine totally changes the power level of Jace's +0!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You would not lose the game from being unable to draw a card.**

This is because the rule that causes you to lose the game states (empahasis mine):

> **104.3c**: If a player is required to **draw** more cards than are left in his or her library, he or she draws the remaining cards, and then loses the game the next time a player would receive priority. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)

and [Omen Machine](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmen%20Machine%5d) says (emphasis mine):

> **Players can't draw cards.**
>   At the beginning of each player's draw step, that player exiles the top card of his or her library. If it's a land card, the player puts it onto the battlefield. Otherwise, the player casts it without paying its mana cost if able.

So what happens is:

- Omen Machine attempts to exile the top card of your library.
- You don't have a top card to your library, so the following steps don't do anything.
- You continue onto your First Main as normal, having not drawn a card and not exiled a card.

This is further supported in the Gatherer Rulings of a similar card, [Maralen of the Mornsong](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=152546) which states:

> While Maralen is on the battlefield, no player can lose the game due to being instructed to draw a card with an empty library.

Comment: The "Maralen of the Mornsong" link is broken.  I don't know why; it all looks spelled right.

Comment: @Brilliand It's because [there's a "Maralen of the Mornsong Avatar" for vanguard](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&special=true&name=+[maralen]). Gatherer fails to find a card when its name has multiple words and those words are also inside another card's name. That makes no sense and impacts many other cards. I've documented it [in the third paragraph of this meta question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/), which is also a request to use another search engine than Gatherer since we keep running into nonsense like this.

Answer (score 7):

You won't lose. The game continues.

Losing a game due to drawing is *very specific to only drawing.* See [the rules on drawing a card](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/cr120/):

> 120.4 A player who attempts to draw a card from a library with no cards in it loses the game the next time a player would receive priority. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)

If something says you're not drawing, you don't, and you can't lose the game this way without drawing.

Omen Machine would try to exile a card and find none to exile. (It won't fizzle, it just won't do anything.)

You continue play with no cards in your hand or library. You've got only whatever is on your battlefield and in your graveyard. Your opponent has whatever it is they have. You'll *probably* lose, but they'll have to find another way to make you lose — such as by removing your Omen Machine.